# How to replace hostname in url in c#?

Tags: c#, url

I have this function

```
    public static string ReplaceHost(string original, string newHostName) {
        UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(original);
        builder.Host = newHostName;
        return builder.Uri.ToString();
    }
```

however the inputs are like this

```
original - https://test.com/a/b/c
newHostName - https://test2.com
```

however this results in an invalid uri exception. I think it's because newHostName shouldn't have the `https://` part. How can I edit this code so it works with my inputs?

Thanks

Comment: You are correct, a host name does not include the scheme. Create a Uri object from your newHostName (don't call it newHostName, because it actually is not a host name but an url; rather call it something like newHostUrl) and then obtain the host name part from that Uri object...

Comment: `return new UriBuilder(original) {Host = new Uri(newHostName).Host}.ToString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ## `Uri.Host`
>
> A String that contains the host name. This is usually the DNS host name or IP address of the server.

You just need to `.Host` part of `newHostName`:

```
public static string ReplaceHost(string original, string newHostName)
{
    UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(original);
    builder.Host = new Uri(newHostName).Host;
    return builder.ToString();
}
```